# How to enumerate My.Setting.Connectionstring in custom control Combobox

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls, propertygrid

I am creating a custom control of type Textbox, and I want to create a combobox property that enumerates all the connections available in the project setting "Connection String".

I am using this code. As you can see, I commented non-working code while I was trying.

```
Private _formatString As String = Nothing

    <Category("Display")>
    <DisplayName("Connection")>
    <Description("Connection string.")>
    <DefaultValue("")>
    <TypeConverter(GetType(FormatStringConverter))>
    Public Property Connection As String
        Get
            Return _formatString
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _formatString = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Class FormatStringConverter
        Inherits StringConverter

        Public Overrides Function GetStandardValuesSupported(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As Boolean
            Return True
        End Function

        Public Overrides Function GetStandardValuesExclusive(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As Boolean
            Return True
        End Function

        Public Overrides Function GetStandardValues(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection
            Dim list As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
            'For Each current In Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
            '    list.Add(current.Name)
            'Next
            'For Each value As Configuration.SettingsPropertyValue In My.Settings.PropertyValues
            '    'MessageBox.Show(value.Name & " - " & value.PropertyValue.ToString)
            '    'list.Add(value.Name & " - " & value.PropertyValue.ToString)
            'Next
            list.Add("")
            list.Add("Currency")
            list.Add("Scientific Notation")
            list.Add("General Number")
            list.Add("Number")
            list.Add("Percent")
            list.Add("Time")
            list.Add("Date")
            Return New StandardValuesCollection(list)
        End Function
    End Class
```

I want to enumerate the connection strings in the project I placed the control in.

The custom control is in a separate project, not the same project of the form I am using.

[edit]
I cannot see the expected results at design-time. I want to choose the connection from a combobox same as tableadapter in dataset [table adapter connection selection from combobox](https://ibb.co/0XqbFP3) at design time. So I want to read and set the connection list available in a form belong to the project I placed the custom textbox in at design time.

Comment: Could it be that a new connection string is added while the code is running?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, No new connection, but the connection can be changed.. and I change it using my.setting("cnn_app") = connection_string, so no "cnn_app" is a variable in combobox i can use to set the connection

Comment: `My.Setting.Connectionstring` does not exist - what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: This custom textbox will have property **Query** **ParameterControl** **Connection** Query will be :"SELECT [ITEM_NAME] FROM [ITEM] WHERE [ID] = ?" ParameterControl : txt_itemID (control holding the parameter for the query) Connection : CNN_PSX (chose from combo) Then I will addhandler to txt_itemID.TextChanged event to execute the query, using the connection string I chose from combo, using txt_itemID.text as parameter and show the result is the custom control textbox Thats the idea

Comment: I will set Query and ParameterControl and Connection at design time, at run time if txt_itemID.text changed, it will execute the query with parameter and display the result in custom textbox

Comment: @AndrewMorton. Yes True. I got that now. in the custom control even if I set the combo to CNN_PSX in the form, I cannot get the connection string from it in the custom control. So I guess i had to pass connection string. It was an idea not implemented yet.. thanks for the info

Comment: Are you still interested in a way to do this?  If so, loading the connection strings stored in the "app.config" file (`My.Settings` connection strings are added to this file) is fairly easy.  If you want to extract directly from `My.Settings`, this gets a bit weird as the project build needs to be up to date to extract the type from the built assembly and create an instance to get the values.

Comment: @TnTinMn Actually Not any more. I will create CNN_CLB in the class library setting where my custom control is build, and when my application start I will set the connection string and use at run time.

Thanks every one for the insight you give me